# How to wait for signal to term executable

Tags: c++, c, signals, posix

I would like to put my main thread to sleep until the application is terminated externally, I think it would be best with sigwait() or sigwaitinfo().

What signals would I need to respond to and how might this look? I'm a bit exhausted by the abundance of examples, or am I imagining the whole thing too easy?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to make some actions before you application is terminated (with SIGTERM). For this you can register a SIGTERM handler, short example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

void sig_handler(int signum)
{
  printf("\nDo some signal handling actions here\n");
  exit( 0 );
}

int main()
{
  signal( SIGTERM, sig_handler ); // Register signal handler
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```